# how to know last click of load more button php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have successfully execute a load more button functionality using 
jQuery - AJAX load() Method, it works like this , display first 3 comments from my db when the page is load , if user click load more button it will load 3 more comments , user click once load 3 more comments until there is no more comments from db.

The problem is when there is no more comments from db , user has to scroll all the way up. which is not very user-friendly, I know can make back to top link to guide user go back , are there any alternative solutions ?

like detect the last click or when there is no more data from db comments , then show less (display only first 3 comments), just like facebook style.
here is my codes

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
<?php if ( more_than_3_reviews($the_post_id)  ): ?>
        var reviews_count = 3 ;
        $("#show_more_reviews").click(function(){
            reviews_count = reviews_count + 3;
            $("#show_more").load("ajax/load_comments.php", {
                new_comments_count : comments_count,
                post_id: <?php echo $the_pro_id; ?>

            });
        });
<?php else: ?>   
        $("#show_more").remove();
<?php endif; ?>
}); 
</script>
```

my backend php file

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        if(isset($_POST['new_comments_count']) and isset($_POST['post_id']) ){

            $comments_count = $_POST['new_comments_count'];
            $the_pro_id = $_POST['post_id'];

            $approved = "approved";
$stmt10 = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT comment_name, product_id,comment_msg, date_time FROM comments WHERE product_id = ? and comment_status = ? LIMIT $comments_count");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt10, "is", $the_pro_id , $approved );
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt10);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt10, $comment_name,$product_id,$comment_msg,$date_time);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt10);


while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt10)){ 

    $get_comment = <<<DELIMETER

    <div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"> {$comment_name} &nbsp; <small>{$date_time}</small> </h4>
        {$comment_msg} 
    </div>
    </div>
    DELIMETER;
    echo $get_comment;     
            }    

        } // post get comments

    }   // if its POST request
```

any assistance would be appreciated .

Comment: i dont understand what you want to happen when there are no more rows to show.

Comment: hi smith ,when there is no more rows , button value becomes show less , when user click , remove all the comments but ONLY shows the first 3 comments.

Comment: Treat the show less button as the indicator that there is no more data.  Then action the show less button to run a query that limits to 3 based on `$post_id `.  Throw a `.scrollTop()` in your Ajax/Jquery method to return.  Or you could reduce your count in the opposite direction (off show less); first way is easier IMO.